# Laravel query merging

Tags: php, sql, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

I have the following tables:
phase, bet, bet_type. 
A phase has many bets and a bet belongs to one phase, a bet has many bet_types and a bet_type belongs to many bets (many to many).
I would like to be able to return all bets for a given phase and bet_types for each bet (a bet consists of many bet_types).

For example:

```
Phase table:
id  name  
1   phase1


Bet table:
id  name  phase
1   bet1  1
2   bet2  1


Bet_Type table:
id  name
1   bet_type1
2   bet_type2


Bet_Bet_Type (connection table):
bet_id   bet_type_id
1        1
1        2
2        1
```

the result I would like to get is:

```
{
    bets: 
    [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "bet1",
            bet_type: 
            [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "bet_type1"
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: "bet_type2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: "bet2",
            bet_type: 
            [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: "bet_type1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I know how to get all the bets of a phase, like this:

```
$bets = Phase::find($phaseId)->bets()->get();
```

But how can I get the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$phase = Phase::with('bets.betTypes')->find($phaseId);
```

This requires to declare relationship methods:

```
// Phase Model
public function bets()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Bet');
}

// Bet Model
public function betTypes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('BetType');
}

// BetType Model
public function bets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Bet');
}
```

So you may use something like this:

```
$phase = Phase::with('bets.betTypes')->find($phaseId);

// Get all bets
$bets = $phase->bets;

// Get all betTypes from first Bet
$betTypes = $phase->bets->first()->betTypes;

// Get all betTypes from second Bet
$betTypes = $phase->bets->get(1)->betTypes;

// Get first betType from second Bet
$betType1 = $phase->bets->get(1)->betTypes->get(0); // or first()
```

If you loop in the view (`Blade`):

```
{{ $phase->name }}
@foreach($phase->bets as $bet)
    {{ $bet->name }}
    @foreach($bet->betTypes as $betType)
        {{ $betType->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```